# hide show div using javascript css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to slowly hide or show my div . what should be the logic in script bellow .When i clicked the button,existing div hiding and another div showing. would anyone please answer.Here is my code snippet.

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('before-e');
    var y = document.getElementById('after-e');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        y.style.display = 'block';
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }

}
```

```css
.favorites-right-before-expand {
    background-color: #5642BE;
    color: #fff;
    height: 155px;
    width: 106px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.matched-body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.per {
    margin-bottom: -8px;
}
.prog-percent {
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.prog-percent {
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.my-progress {
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.favorites-right-before-expand button {
    color: #D6DA22;
    font-size: 8px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background: none;
    border-style: none;
}
.per {
    margin-bottom: -8px;
}
.prog-percent-after {
    margin-left: 21px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.prog-percent-after {
    margin-left: 21px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.my-progress-after {
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-right: 42px;
}
.expand ul {
    list-style: none;
    color: #D6DA22;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.favorites-right {
    background-color: #5642BE;
    color: #fff;
    height: 180px;
    width: 142px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="favorites-right" style="display: none;" id="after-e">
                <div class="prog-percent-after per">80%</div>
                <div class="prog-percent-after"> MATCHED</div>
              <div class="progress my-progress-after">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:80%">
                </div>
              </div>
               <div class="expand">
                <ul>
                  <li> You both do not smoke</li>
                  <li> You both live in Bangldesh</li>
                  <li> Ridhika seems to like photography</li>
                  <a href="#" style="color: #D6DA22;font-size: 10px;text-decoration: underline;">See more>></a>
                </ul>     
              </div>
            </div><!-- end favorites-right-->
 <div class="favorites-right-before-expand" id="before-e">
              <div class="matched-body">
                <div class="prog-percent per">80%</div>
                <div class="prog-percent"> MATCHED</div>
              <div class="progress my-progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:80%">
                      </div>
              </div>
              <button onclick="myFunction()" class="expand_button">Expand Categories>></button>
              </div><!--end matched-body-->
            </div><!-- end favorites-right-before-expand -->
```

Comment: In general, **hide** or **show** with delay can be done like: `jQuery("#something").hide(400);`. [DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: If you want it to fade in and out, that can be done too with jQuery `element.fadeIn(1000);` for example

Comment: I tried fade in hide.but i need to be hide existing div with all and it will replace with another new div. when i am using hide or fade In this is not working exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fade one element out, then fade in another one after the animation has completed, you can pass in a function into the second parameter of the `.fadeOut` function. In this function, you `.fadeIn` the second element.

**Here's an Example**

500 is the delay in milliseconds

```
$('#first-element').fadeOut(500, function() {
    $('#second-element').fadeIn();
});
```

**The example in your code**

```js
function myFunction() {
    $('#before-e').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#after-e').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

```css
.favorites-right-before-expand {
    background-color: #5642BE;
    color: #fff;
    height: 155px;
    width: 106px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.matched-body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.per {
    margin-bottom: -8px;
}
.prog-percent {
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.prog-percent {
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.my-progress {
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.favorites-right-before-expand button {
    color: #D6DA22;
    font-size: 8px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background: none;
    border-style: none;
}
.per {
    margin-bottom: -8px;
}
.prog-percent-after {
    margin-left: 21px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.prog-percent-after {
    margin-left: 21px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.my-progress-after {
    height: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-left: 21px;
    margin-right: 42px;
}
.expand ul {
    list-style: none;
    color: #D6DA22;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.favorites-right {
    background-color: #5642BE;
    color: #fff;
    height: 180px;
    width: 142px;
    padding-top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="favorites-right" style="display: none;" id="after-e">
                <div class="prog-percent-after per">80%</div>
                <div class="prog-percent-after"> MATCHED</div>
              <div class="progress my-progress-after">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:80%">
                </div>
              </div>
               <div class="expand">
                <ul>
                  <li> You both do not smoke</li>
                  <li> You both live in Bangldesh</li>
                  <li> Ridhika seems to like photography</li>
                  <a href="#" style="color: #D6DA22;font-size: 10px;text-decoration: underline;">See more>></a>
                </ul>     
              </div>
            </div><!-- end favorites-right-->
 <div class="favorites-right-before-expand" id="before-e">
              <div class="matched-body">
                <div class="prog-percent per">80%</div>
                <div class="prog-percent"> MATCHED</div>
              <div class="progress my-progress">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:80%">
                      </div>
              </div>
              <button onclick="myFunction()" class="expand_button">Expand Categories>></button>
              </div><!--end matched-body-->
            </div><!-- end favorites-right-before-expand -->
```

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan No problem! Please remember to mark the correct answer by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are making this harder on yourself than you need to be.  Assuming that you are using jQuery you can easily just do the following.

```
function toggleDivs () {
  $('#after-e').toggle();
  $('#before-e').toggle();
}
```

The [toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will display or hide the elements based on their current state in the dom.

Comment: And i need to hide the existing button

Answer (score 0):

You can add these lines to your code in order to get it through CSS.

```
.favorites-right-before-expand {
    background-color: #5642BE;
    color: #fff;
    height: 155px;
    width: 106px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
(yourvariable).style.display = "block";
```

then add the css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

then,

```
.yourdiv {
-webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s;
animation: fadein 0.5s; 
}
```